# utils.ts:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, charts, axios

I want to push label data on chartjs with json data from my database but,
When I try to run this code it gives me this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')  utils.ts:57

When I console log the response it gives the data properly no error with the data hooks from api
Why does it happen? How can I make it work?

```
function Chart() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    data();
  }, []);

  const data = () => {
    const ormawa = [];
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/proposal?search_query=${keyword}`).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      for (const dataObj of res.data.result){
        ormawa.push(dataObj.nama_organisasi);
      }
      setChartData({
        labels: ormawa,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Nama Ormawa",
            data: [8, 7, 8, 6, 8, 14],
            backgroundColor: ' rgb(10, 124, 92)',
          },
        ],
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(ormawa);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={chartData}></Bar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `.map()`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is because when you call data() (inside the **useEffect** hook) you are generating a **synchronous** process but the *Axios* function is **asynchronous** (is a promise / using then) this executes after the return (when chartData is {} yet).

Possible solution is to call data() in asynchronous form like:

```js
 

function Chart() {
 const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
 const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const ormawa = [];
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/proposal?search_query=${keyword}`).then(res => {
         for (const dataObj of res.data.result){
           ormawa.push(dataObj.nama_organisasi);
         }
         setChartData({
         labels: ormawa,
         datasets: [
          {
            label: "Nama Ormawa",
            data: [8, 7, 8, 6, 8, 14],
            backgroundColor: ' rgb(10, 124, 92)',
          },
         ],
       });
     })
     fetchData()
      .catch(console.error);
}, []);

 return (
         <div>
          {chartData
            ?
             <Bar data={chartData}></Bar>
            :
             <span>Loading...</span>
            }
         </div>
        );
};
```

PS: Maybe you need to change your Axios /get function to something like this: https://rapidapi.com/guides/axios-async-await